# What should an object be called that contains only setters and getters?

Tags: design-patterns

Suppose there's an object that contains only setters and getters:

```
class Config
{
    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setLanguage(String language)
    {
        this.language = language;
    }

    public String getLanguage()
    {
        return this.language;
    }

    // And so on, you got the point!
}
```

There are several terms that describe such objects:

- DAO (Data Access Object)
- DTO (Data Transfer Object)
- VO (Value object)

Here lies my confusion:

It can be called **Data Access Object**, because it's responsible for data access. It can be called **Data Transfer Object**, because it might be responsible for transferring data between different objects. And finally, it can be called **Value Object**, because it has no behaviour and contains only values.

What are the origins of these different terms, which term should I choose in which context, and why?

Comment: Ooo semantics. I always just call it "mutable struct" and move on. I also sometimes will call it POD (plain old data), but that has special meaning in C/C++, in which case people call it POCO (plain old C++ object). I'm partial to calling it POO. In the end, it doesn't really matter what you call it as long as you define it in your documentation and use it consistently.

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6582/on-the-troubles-of-naming-and-terminology

Comment: It's a [record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Record_%28computer_science%29). I don't even bother with getters/setters for these - their only value is moving data from one point to another, and if any processing needs to happen I'd rather make it explicit instead of hiding it in a setter or getter and pretending I have anything more than a dumb collection of data.

Comment: To whomever is suggesting to close this question as "primarily opinion based" - these different terms have a historical background / background from different schools of thought - there is nothing opinionated in their *origin* (only when thinking in terms of "which one is better", but that was not the question).

Comment: @DocBrown `only when thinking in terms of "which one is better", but that was not the question` He concludes with "Please explain, which term you would choice [sic] and why." I don't see how this is anything more than a thinly-veiled poll. He understands the rationale behind those names, he just wants to know which one is more common or popular.

Comment: @Doval: see my edit, if that's your only concern, it can be easily fixed.

Comment: @DocBrown I can live with that. Vote retracted.

Comment: An object...with no functionality...is not an object. A donut...with no hole...is a danish...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I certainly wouldn't call it a value object because that conflicts with the idea in domain-driven-design. Going from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_object):

> In computer science, a value object is a small object that represents a simple entity whose equality is not based on identity: i.e. two value objects are equal when they have the same value, not necessarily being the same object.

For example, a `Person` might have a `Name`. The `Person` is not a value object because even if they change their name, they are still the same person. Their equality is based on identity. The `Name` itself on the other hand is a value object- change any letter in that name and it becomes a new, different name.

As for what to call these, another term I've commonly heard is [Property Bag](http://www.anujvarma.com/property-bagsa-life-saver-for-the-oo-developers/). This is maybe a bit more of a C#-centric name than Java-centric, but it still describes the same idea. The difference between this and DTO/DAO is that it's being used to describe what the class *is* rather than what it's *for*. Whether this is more or less appropriate depends on the situation.

Comment: 'Property bag' fits the best to this specific style of class design, IMHO. Most C# developers would understand what you meant.

Answer (score 11):

A [DAO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object) class usually has the [CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) operations like save, update, and delete. Whereas the DTO is just an object that holds data. So there is actually a difference between those two. The term then depends on what the object does.

A VO and DTO used to be synonyms: early [Java EE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Enterprise_Edition) literature used the term value object to describe a DTO, but it changed it in a later version.
"A Value Object doesn't have any identity. It is entirely identified by its value and is immutable." ~ http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/value_object_vs_data_transfer

Answer (score 4):

I would call them structs. An old school name for old school design.

1. DAOs contain persistence-related functionality. That's not a DAO.
2. That could be a poorly implemented value object. Value objects should generally be immutable and they should have proper constructors. (However, a configuration could very well be an example of a value-like object that could be reasonably designed as mutable. It could be thought of as a map with fixed keys.)
3. A DTO could look like that, but an object is a DTO only when its sole purpose is to carry data over remote interfaces or such.

Answer (score 1):

As others have answered, `DAO` and `DTO` reflect the role of the Object whether you want to use it in a persistence layer or to transfer informations in a call.

A value Object should be immutable.

Since your code is in Java (and the terminology is quite Java Oriented), the term that comes to my mind is [JavaBean](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/spec-136004.html) but your class should implement `Serializable`.

I think you should have a look at [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612334/difference-between-dto-vo-pojo-javabeans) on Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

I've heard and used both Data Access Object and Data Transfer Object, though I usually just call them Data Models (Objects) because it implies a container and doesn't imply what you are actually going to be doing with it.

Answer (score 0):

In the .NET world, your class qualifies as a [plain old CLR object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_CLR_Object) (POCO).

In the Java world, you have [plain old Java objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object) (POJOs).

Comment: Not entirely sure I agree.  OP's objects have no methods, just setters & getters. POCOs and POJOs might be very complex, just unencumbered with external dependencies (i.e., inheritance from a particular framework).  What am I missing?